# Server files from /media/ using nginx

Tags: nginx

I am writing a small app which is intended for personal use, using Flask + nginx.

I have setup nginx and flask, and nginx quite happily servers the static assets of the Flask app. What I want to do now is server all media files from `/media/` on an Ubuntu server box.

Basically I want nginx to be able to access and server whatever files are available at `/media` which could be a usb drive, sd card, whatever.

I have set up nginx with an alias for static and media:

```
location /static {
    alias /path/to/my/app/static;
}

location /media {
    alias /media;
}
```

and I'm pretty sure that nginx is happy because if I copy the static path to the media alias I get my static files.

At the moment when I point to `localhost/media`, I am just getting an empty page (not the nginx 403 forbidden page).

I have tried changing permissions of `/media` to 744 - no change. Is there perhaps some fundamental reason why I can't 'see' the `/media` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a permission problem. The executable bit is required to go through directories so I guess that `chmod -R 0755 /media` would do the trick. There is a way to apply this only to directories wich would be safer but even on all files it's not a problem for personnal use.

Comment: So after a little fix and changing of permission I can see the `/media` dir with nginx. However, I cannot go any further down the tree into the SD card. Now I get the actual 403 page. To ensure that nginx will be able to see all files on any usb drive/ sd card, what would be the best way? Should I change nginx permissions to root?

Comment: Dont give nginx root permissions, it is a bad idea according to anyone. I think that where you are it also depends of the filesystem type of your removable media. Here I have to say that I am not sure of the following but maybe giving www-data the users group can help you. It is the same idea than running nginx as root but much less dangerous. It's worth a try.

Comment: @Darwin Tech - If you could find out to which user and groups the files on the media belong that would be of great help.